# Calculating sales commissions using a sharing schedule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to output sales commissions based on a sharing schedule. I have 2 problems:

1. How to write the query without using an inline subquery
2. How to output the salesperson and their remaining commission if they have not shared 100% of it.

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @SALES TABLE
               (
                   Id INT,
                   SalesPerson VARCHAR(10),
                   Commission MONEY
               )

INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES(1,'Amy',    100.00)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES(2,'Lisa',   200.00)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES(3,'Joe',    300.00)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES(4,'Wendy',  400.00)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES(5,'Mike',   500.00)


DECLARE @SHARE_SCHEDULE TABLE
                        (
                            GIVER INT,
                            TAKER INT,
                            PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(9,2)
                        )

INSERT INTO @SHARE_SCHEDULE VALUES(3, 1, .5)
INSERT INTO @SHARE_SCHEDULE VALUES(3, 2, .5)
INSERT INTO @SHARE_SCHEDULE VALUES(4, 5, .4)

SELECT 
    S.SalesPerson,
    S.Commission + (SELECT SUM(Commission) 
                    FROM @SALES 
                    WHERE ID = SS.GIVER) * SS.PERCENTAGE Commission
 FROM @SALES S
 JOIN @SHARE_SCHEDULE SS ON SS.TAKER = S.ID
```

Expected results:

```
SalesPerson Commission
Amy         250.00
Lisa        350.00
Wendy       240.00
Mike        660.00
```

Comment: can you be a giver and a taker?

Comment: What is the purpose of Giver and Taker, and you are inserting 3 rows in `@SHARE_SCHEDULE` with Taker ID as 1,2,5 then in expected output you need `Wendy` also, little bit confusing. Can you elaborate.

Comment: Giver is the Salesperson's Id who's giving up a % of their commission , Taker is the Salesperson's Id who's getting the shared %.  One can't be a Giver and a Taker .

Comment: Wendy is needed in the output because she's only giving up 40% of her commissions. Joe is excluded because he gives away 100%

Comment: @ddrjca What if Joe starts getting say 10 % from Mike? Will he be included?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi a SalesPerson can't be a giver and a taker.

Comment: @ddrjca Ok posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with Q as
(
    select S.*, coalesce(J.share, 0) received, coalesce(K.share, 0) given from SALES S

    outer apply
    (
        select sum(H.PERCENTAGE * L.Commission) as share from SHARE_SCHEDULE H 
            inner join SALES L on L.Id = H.GIVER
            where H.TAKER = S.Id

    ) J

    outer apply
    (
        select sum(H.PERCENTAGE * L.Commission) as share from SHARE_SCHEDULE H 
            inner join SALES L on L.Id = H.GIVER
            where H.GIVER = S.Id
    ) K
)

select SalesPerson, (Commission + received - given) TotalCommission from Q 
    where (Commission + received - given) > 0
```

**J** is the sum of all shared commission *received* by a sales person

**K** is the sum of all shared commission *given* by a sales person

The intermediate result (`select * from Q`) looks like:

```
Id  SalesPerson Commission received     given
--- ----------- ---------- ------------ -----------
1   Amy         100.00     150.000000   0.000000
2   Lisa        200.00     150.000000   0.000000
3   Joe         300.00     0.000000     300.000000
4   Wendy       400.00     0.000000     160.000000
5   Mike        500.00     160.000000   0.000000
```

The final result looks like:

```
SalesPerson     TotalCommission (= commission + received - given)
-----------     ---------------
Amy             250.000000
Lisa            350.000000
Wendy           240.000000
Mike            660.000000
```

[**Rextester Demo**](http://rextester.com/WZIXH48417)

Comment: why the `COALESCE` over a simpler `ISNULL`?

Comment: @Eli -- Force of habit; I usually have to deal with many potentialy null columns. You're right that `ISNULL` would be more idiomatic SQL in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    S.Id,
    S.SalesPerson, 
    S.Commission + ISNULL(G.GIVEN,0) +ISNULL(T.TAKEN,0) Commission 
FROM @SALES S
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            GIVER, 
            -SUM(PERCENTAGE*S.Commission)  GIVEN
        FROM @SHARE_SCHEDULE SS 
            JOIN @SALES S
                ON SS.GIVER=S.Id
        GROUP BY GIVER
    ) G ON G.GIVER=S.Id
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
         SELECT 
            TAKER,
            SUM(PERCENTAGE*S.Commission)  TAKEN
         FROM @SHARE_SCHEDULE SS 
            JOIN @SALES S
                ON SS.GIVER=S.Id
         GROUP BY TAKER
    )T ON T.TAKER=S.Id
WHERE S.Commission + ISNULL(G.GIVEN,0) >0
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/MENM66958)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be split into three different parts:

1. The Original Table SALES
2. Givers with values given-away
3. Takers with values as received

Then combine these to get the output required.

```
select 
S.SalesPerson,
       (S.Commission  --original commision
           +       
         (ISNULL(tempTaker.Commission, 0)) -- plus recevied as TAKER
         -
         (ISNULL(tempGiver.Commission, 0))  -- minus paid as GIVER

        )
      Commission

from @SALES s

--tempTaker 
left outer join 
(
    select ss1.TAKER, SUM(ss1.PERCENTAGE * s1.Commission) Commission 
    FROM @SALES S1 
    inner join @SHARE_SCHEDULE ss1 on s1.Id = ss1.GIVER
    group by ss1.TAKER
) tempTaker on tempTaker.TAKER = s.id

--tempGiver
left outer join 
(
    select ss1.GIVER, SUM(ss1.PERCENTAGE * s1.Commission) Commission 
    FROM @SALES S1 
    inner join @SHARE_SCHEDULE ss1 on s1.Id = ss1.GIVER
    group by ss1.GIVER

) tempGiver on tempGiver.GIVER = s.id

--filter, the final value should be greater than ZERO.
where (s.Commission 
        +        
         ISNULL(tempTaker.Commission, 0) 
        -
         ISNULL(tempGiver.Commission, 0)
         )
          > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with some CTE's, one each for the names, the amounts which they gave, and the amount which they received from others. I've also formatted the commission amounts as having two decimal points.

```
;WITH base AS (
 SELECT 
    SalesPerson
    ,Commission
    ,id
 FROM @SALES
 ),
 commission_given AS (
    SELECT
        S.GIVER
        ,SUM(base.Commission * s.PERCENTAGE) * -1 commission_given
    FROM @SHARE_SCHEDULE s
    INNER JOIN base ON s.GIVER = base.Id
    GROUP BY S.GIVER, S.PERCENTAGE
 ),
  commission_received AS (
    SELECT
        S.taker
        ,SUM(base.Commission * s.PERCENTAGE)as commission_received
    FROM @SHARE_SCHEDULE s
    INNER JOIN base ON s.giver = base.Id
    GROUP BY S.taker, S.PERCENTAGE
 ),
 TOTAL_COMMISSION AS (
    SELECT
        BASE.SalesPerson
        ,BASE.Commission + ISNULL(cs.commission_given,0) + ISNULL(cr.commission_received,0) AS TOTAL_COMMISSION
    FROM BASE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commission_given AS cs ON BASE.Id = cs.GIVER
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commission_received cr on base.id = cr.taker
 )
 SELECT 
    SalesPerson
    ,CAST(TOTAL_COMMISSION AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS TOTAL_COMMISSION 
 FROM TOTAL_COMMISSION
 WHERE TOTAL_COMMISSION > 0
```

working demo: 
http://rextester.com/live/NWQIR26309

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves your problem:

```
SELECT 
    S.SalesPerson,
    MAX(S.Commission) 
        + Sum(IsNull(ResPlus.Value,0)) 
        - Sum(IsNull(ResSubt.Value,0)) Commission
FROM @SALES S
LEFT JOIN @SHARE_SCHEDULE SS ON SS.TAKER = S.ID
LEFT JOIN @SHARE_SCHEDULE SS2 ON SS2.GIVER = S.ID 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SS.PERCENTAGE * SUM(Commission) FROM @SALES WHERE ID = SS.GIVER) ResPlus(Value)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SS2.PERCENTAGE * SUM(Commission) FROM @SALES WHERE ID = SS2.GIVER) ResSubt(Value)
group by S.SalesPerson, S.ID
having MAX(S.Commission) + Sum(IsNull(ResPlus.Value,0)) - Sum(IsNull(ResSubt.Value,0)) > 0
order by S.ID
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/CVPYF58029)